# How do I make a vim command run automatically with .vimrc?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I run the following `vim` command to change the colour of highlighted columns to something more palatable than the default red:

`:highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=235 guibg=#2c2d27`

rather than run this manually everytime I start vim, I'd like to automate this. But how? I've tried adding the following to `.vimrc`:

`highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=235 guibg=#2c2d27`

But that has no effect (no errors, it's just ignored after restart). Am I doing something wrong? I got the command from this Q:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447109/showing-a-different-background-colour-in-vim-past-80-characters

But it didn't seem to shed light on my particular problem.

Comment: Add it to the colourscheme you are currently using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select a `colorscheme` prior to adding any `highlight` commands in your `.vimrc` file.

#### Example

```
colorscheme desert
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=235 guibg=#2c2d27
```

#### References

- [How do I change my Vim highlight line to not be an underline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640276/how-do-i-change-my-vim-highlight-line-to-not-be-an-underline)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your colorscheme had overrided your configuration. You can override it by the way in @slm's answer or create another configuration for colorscheme in `~/.vim/after/colors/<colorscheme name>.vim`.

But you can always override settings in all colorscheme by adding this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=235 guibg=#2d2d27
```